# Relative Paths for SystemJS & ES module imports

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm, systemjs, node-modules

I'm having an issue with importing Angular2 components when using SystemJS and ES import syntax.

Project structure:

```
ROOT
|_src
  |_client
    |_app
      |_frameworks
        |_il8n
        |_analytics
      |_main
        |_components
        |_pages
        |_utility
```

Let's say I have a file: `ROOT/src/client/app/frameworks/il8n/language-service.ts` and another file: `ROOT/src/client/app/main/pages/login/login.ts`. In login.ts I want to import language.ts, so one way to do that is like so:

`//login.ts
import { LanguageService } from '../../../../frameworks/il8n/language-service';`

Another way to do that, using barrels, is like so:

`//login.ts
import { LanguageService } from '../../../../frameworks/index';`

where `frameworks/index.ts` is doing `export * from './il8n/language-service';`

I don't want to do `../../../` etc every time I need to import something; it would be nice if I could just do `import { LanguageService } from 'frameworks';`

So far, I've been able to get my build process working using SystemJS's ["map" option](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map) like so:

```
map: {
      frameworks: 'src/client/app/frameworks/index',
      components: 'src/client/app/main/components/index',
      pages: 'src/client/app/main/pages/index'
    }
```

However, my IDE is complaining (all IntelliSense functionality is completely broken) anytime I do something like:

```
`import { LanguageService } from 'frameworks';`
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "frameworks": ["client/app/frameworks"],
            "components": ["client/app/main/components"],
            "pages": ["client/app/main/pages"],
            "utility": ["client/app/main/utility"]
        }
    },
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Is there a way to satisfy both my IDE and the SystemJS build configuration so that I can do "simple" imports?

Comment: which IDE version do you use?

Comment: I use WebStorm 2016.2

Comment: could you please share you project? The functionality must work for WS2016.2

Comment: I actually got it semi-working, I'm going to post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this question was based around the Angular2 Seed (Advanced) repo found [here](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced). I posted an [issue](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced/issues/180) there as well (where you can see the exact fix). Long story short:

You need TypeScript 2.0 to use the `paths` and `baseUrl` options in your tsconfig file. Then in your SystemJS config file, you need to add some configuration to the `paths` and `packages` options as follows:

```
packages: {
  ...
  frameworks: { defaultExtension: js, main: index.js }
  ...
},
paths: {
  ...
  frameworks: 'relative/path/to/frameworks/folder'
  ...
}
```

`index.ts` is a file INSIDE your `frameworks` folder which exports the modules in that directory. For example, if you had a `language.component.ts` file somewhere inside your frameworks directory, in the `frameworks/index.ts` file you would do:

`export * from 'path/to/language.component';`.

This allows you to do `import {LanguageComponent} from 'frameworks';` in your project (as long as you are outside the `frameworks` directory).

Hope this helps!