# Angular2 import absolute path or custom path (typescript 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, path, tsconfig

In our angular2 project, we put all our models ts files in a specific folder : /app/common/model/*.
I can call them in my components with relatives paths, but it's very laborious.
So 2 solutions, best is a custom path: [StackOverflow: Relative Paths for SystemJS & ES module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618257/relative-paths-for-systemjs-es-module-imports).
But my IDE can not find the path. Here is my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "built",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "mymodel/*": [
        "app/common/model/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In my component:
`import { Address } from 'mymodel/address.model';`

IDE: [ts] Cannot find module....
I tried with or without * in path

Second solution : [Stackoverflow: Angular 2, imports between different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547364/angular-2-imports-between-different-folders)

IDE and compilation are ok, with full path in component :
`import { Address } from 'common/model/address.model';`

And the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "built",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "app/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But we have 404 on page load for all models.
Maybe a config in systemjs file ?

In both cases, I think that "outdir" parameter is the problem, and we are missing something.

Many thanks for help!

Regards,

TypeScript: 2.0.6
Angular: 2.0.0

Comment: Which IDE are you using? In mine (IntelliJ/Webstorm), I almost never type an import: the IDE adds it for me.

Comment: Visual Studio Code. In yours is it absolute path ?

Comment: First solution is working great with other IDE... Sorry, it's a phony problem

Answer (score 2):

After struggling by searching over internet n trying to understand what exactly problem and trying different troubleshooting option, I came to know **baseUrl** and **Path** how works together

***Note: This solution  is for Angular Cli 1.x*** . Not sure about other tool,

If you use **baseUrl:"."** like below it works in VScode but not while compiling

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@myproject/*": ["src/app/*"]
    }    
}
```

As far my understanding and my working app and checked in *angular aio* code,  I suggest use as **baseUrl:""src** like below

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@myproject/*": ["app/*"],
      "testing/*": ["testing/*"]
    }    
}
```

By having base URL as source(src directory), compiler properly resolves modules.

I hope this helps to people resolve this kind of issue.

Comment: "If you use baseUrl:"." like below it works in VScode but not while compiling"  - That's really important. Thanks

Comment: Is this working in newer version because I have tried in all the ways and I couldn't able to refer with above path.